# Query using hive CLI data is visible but if query using HUE no data found for multiple directory hdfs location

Tags: hadoop, hive, cloudera, cloudera-cdh, hue

I created a hive table using

```
location '/user/hive/test/day=allDataInThisFile'
```

Hive CLI Query: `select * from table;` -> works
HUE_Hive Edditor: used the same query -> works

Now I created Hive table using multiple partitioned directories with

```
location '/user/hive/test'
```

Here data is contained in following directory structure:

```
'/user/hive/test/day=monday'
'/user/hive/test/day=tuesday'
'/user/hive/test/day=wednesday'
```

Hive CLI Query: `select * from table;` -> works
HUE_Hive Edditor: used the same query -> NOT Working

Can someone please let me know what is the issue here?

Comment: "multiple directory"?

Comment: I have edited the question: basically while creating hive table if the location directly points to a hdfs file then no issue, but if i point to a directory, no data is seen on hue

Comment: Hive CLI doesn't use HiveServer2. Try the same in Beeline